# SSLException from HTTPS Request through socket over SOCKS Proxy

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, https, socks

Internet networking newbie here. I'm attempting to send https requests from a Node JS server using the 'socks' npm module through a socks proxy to a Java HTTPS server. I can make individual https requests through the proxy without a socket fine, for example using the 'socks5-https-client' npm module.

I expect back a 200 OK response from my request but instead the Java server throws an SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection error.

My Node JS code is very simple:

```
const options  = {
  proxy: {
    host: '<proxy ip>',
    port: 1080,
    type: 5
  },

  destination: {
    host: '<java server ip>',
    port: 443
  },

  command: 'connect'
};

try {
  const info = await SocksClient.createConnection(options);

  info.socket.write('GET /users HTTP/1.1\nAuthorization: Basic <token>\n\n');
  info.socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
} catch (err) {
  // Handle errors
}
```

The Java server code is:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket listenSocket = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(portNum, 50);

boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Logger.logMessage("interrupted during accept()");
        done = true;
        break;
    }

    InputStream in  = clientSocket.getInputStream();

    // Read the initial request line from the client
    ByteArrayOutputStream inLineA = new ByteArrayOutputStream(100);
    int ch = -1;
    try {
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        while ((ch = in.read()) != '\n' && ch != -1)
            inLineA.write((byte) ch);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        clientSocket.close();
        continue;
    }

[ ... process HTTP request here ]
}
```

After a lot of googling, I thought the issue was because the 'socks' module uses net.Socket which is not secure. However, when I switch it out for a tls.TLSSocket, it results in a proxy connection timeout.

How can I connect a socket through the proxy and send https requests? Is there an issue with my thinking?

Comment: You need to use a 'plain' (TCP) socket _to_ the proxy to issue it the connection info, then TLS protocol on the proxied connection to the appserver. In short, use tls.TLSSocket (with suitable options) to wrap info.socket. Also, your HTTP is nonstandard and broken. HTTP header lines must be terminated by CR LF (Java and JS \r\n) not just \n. The server should look for the blank line ending the header in addition to or even instead of EOF, because with TLS (at least through 1.2) the client CAN'T half-close, plus AFAICT SOCKS doesn't specify half-close so I wouldn't rely on it even for TCP. ...

Comment: ... Also for HTTP/1.1 the Host: header is mandatory (although some servers, like yours, don't care about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to dave_thompson_085. It worked after wrapping the TCP socket returned in a TLS socket like so:

```
Socks.SocksClient.createConnection(options)
          .then(info => {
            const tlsSocket= tls.connect(
              {
                host: <java server ip>,
                port: 443,
                socket: info.socket
              },
              () => {
                tlsSocket.write('GET /users HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic <token>\r\nHost: <java server ip>:443\r\n\r\n');
              }
            );

            tlsSocket.on("data", function(data) {
              // do something with data
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```